# how can I save part of the summary output in r into a specific column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the following manner

```
name<-c('z','z','z','d','d','d')
area<-c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
df<-data.frame(area,name)
(df.1<-data.frame(summary(df$area)))
```

where I get the following output

```
  summary.df.area.
A                2
B                3
C                1
```

As you can see the `A,B,C` values have not been assigned to any specific column, how can I assign these values into a column called `area ID`

so that it looks like

```
   area ID     summary.df.area.
    A                2
    B                3
    C                1
```

Comment: Do `getS3method("summary", "factor")`, notice it calls `table()` so why not just do `as.data.frame(table(factor(c("A","A","B","B","B","C"))))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
df.1<-data.frame(summary(df$area))
df.1$'area ID' <- rownames(df.1)

 df.1
  summary.df.area. area ID
A                2       A
B                3       B
C                1       C
```

To order it:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(df.1$'area ID',df.1$ summary.df.area.)
# add whatever column names you want
colnames(df.1) <- c('ID','summary')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
(df.1<-data.frame(area_ID = names(summary(df$area)),
                  summary = summary(df$area)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  area_ID summary
#A       A       2
#B       B       3
#C       C       1
```

---

Another option is `stack`

```
stack(summary(df$area))
#  values ind
#1      2   A
#2      3   B
#3      1   C
```

But then you'd need to rename your columns obviously.

Answer (score 0):

**One-liner solution**

```
cbind(data.frame("area ID"=rownames(df.1)), df.1)

##   area.ID summary.df.area.
## A       A                2
## B       B                3
## C       C                1
```

**Making a function out of it**

And generalized to a function:

```
# function returning the data frame with rownames as first column
# which has the title given in `firstColName`.
rownamesAsColumn <- function(df, firstColName) {
  res <- cbind(data.frame(firstCol=rownames(df)), df)
  colnames(res) <- c(firstColName, colnames(df))
  res
} 

rownamesAsColumn(df.1, "area ID")

##   area.ID summary.df.area.
## A       A                2
## B       B                3
## C       C                1
```

The trick is to generate a data frame out of `rownames(df.1)` by `data.frame()`
and thereby also naming the column by `data.frame(newname=rownames(df.1))`.
After that, `cbind()` overtakes the column names.